# How to check if a user's "email" exists in database in api.php file in Laravel? And get response in React Native app

Tags: php, laravel, react-native, post, axios

I have a mobile app where a user enters their email address and phone number, I am trying to check whether the email already exists in the database by making an axios post request to my laravel application in the api file where I have created a '/check-email'/ route but all I'm receiving is a promise rejection error.

This is my post route in api.php:

```
// Check Email

Route::post('/check-email', function (Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ]);

    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    if ($user === null) {
        return response()->json(['status' => 'success']);
    }
});
```

And my User model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'ttlock_username',
        'ttlock_password',
        'push_token',
        'os'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'two_factor_recovery_codes',
        'two_factor_secret',
        'ttlock_username',
        'ttlock_password',
        'push_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'profile_photo_url',
    ];

    public function bookings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Booking::class);
    }

    public function firstPromoFree()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UsedPromoCode::class)->where('promo_code', 'PODONUS');

    }
    
    public function devices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PushNotification::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

And my React Native function which calls the post route, passing in the email state:

```
  function checkEmailUser() {
    axios
      .post(BASE_PATH + '/api/check-email', {
        email: email,
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        if (response.data.success) {
          setEmailChecked(true);
          console.log('Email is available');
        } else {
          setEmailChecked(false);
          Alert.alert('A user with this email already exists');
        }
      });
  }
```

I'm sure this is pretty close to being right but can't quite figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Can you log, what is the value of $user after this line:     **$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();**

Comment: Do you always get the error, or only when entering an already used email address? In the latter's case, I presume you get the error because nothing will be returned from the API. Either return something from the API, or add a `.catch((error))` to the Axios request and handle the `setEmailChecked(false)` stuff there.

Comment: Do not tag this question with react-native tag.

Comment: @Alex yep, always getting the error regardless of the email being in the database or not. I thought in the api I was returning json response of 'success' which I expected to see logged in the console when logging 'response.data' so have an issue elsewhere

Comment: Either way I'd add the `.catch((error))` to your Axios request, that way you can actually see what's going wrong.

Comment: thanks for your help @Alex - annoyingly, I had a mistake where my BASE_PATH was wrong but I added the .catch and seems a better practice so thank you